# Get individual sheet size of an excel sheet using openXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am using C# openXML library to read an excel book which has multiple sheets.

There are two approaches to read the individual sheets data.

1. Read all rows at once
2. Read rows one by one

Based on the individual sheet size, the code will decide which approach to choose.

So is there a way to get the size of an individual sheet?

Comment: have a look at [`Worksheet.SheetDimension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.worksheet.sheetdimension(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ExcelDataReader. 
This method dinamically change table size for each table you have in a loop.

```
IExcelDataReader excel;
DataSet ds;

using (var fs = File.OpenRead("C://somepath"))
{
    excel = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs, null, { Password = "somepass" });

    ds = excel.AsDataSet();
}

foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    var numberOfRows = dt.Rows.Count;
    var numberOfColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
}
```

Comment: this does not really answer the question **So is there a way to get the size of an individual sheet?** ...

Comment: It answers in a part :) I think dt.Rows.Count and dt.Columns.Count describes a size

Comment: @bar-tech the OP has already said that they are able to read all rows, but wants to know the size before deciding on the optimal method for reading those rows.